# Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object error :

Tags: php

```
class Authorization {
    public $vk_id;
    public $eu_name;
    public $eu_society;
    public $eu_notes;
    public $eu_want_team;
    public $query;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->vk_id = $_POST['vk_id'];
        $this->eu_name = $_POST['eu_name'];
        $this->eu_society = $_POST['eu_society'];
        $this->eu_notes = $_POST['eu_notes'];
        $this->eu_want_team = $_POST['eu_want_team'];
    }

    function query($query) {
        $this->query = $query;
        $this->STH = $this->DBH->prepare($this->query);
        $this->STH->execute();
        $this->STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    }
}
$auth = new Authorization();
$auth->query("INSERT INTO users (vk_id, eu_name, eu_society, eu_want_team, eu_notes) VALUES ($auth->vk_id, $auth->eu_name, $auth->eu_society, $auth->eu_want_team, $auth->eu_notes);");
```

It tells - : `Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object line 21`

```
line 21 is         $this->STH = $this->DBH->prepare($this->query);
```

What's bad there?

Comment: Where do you define $this->DBH?

Comment: Did you define your db connection in the script?

Comment: You are still concatenating the query. That is not how prepares statements are used.

Comment: I will do the prepared statements.. Anyway i've found answer on it. Sorry guys.

Comment: that query is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Are you trying to do a prepared query, because this is not how -that- works.

Comment: @TigranMuradyan - if you've found the answer, you can add it as an answer yourself, and accept it when you're able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because your class does not have `$DBH` field, so it does not exist, so it is non-object.

Probably you missed instantiating or injecting the `$DBH` value in the constructor.